# response is stuck on nginx proxy in swarm

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-swarm

I have swarm cluster having 3 nginx nodes and 3 server nodes
I send request to it and async server 5 minutes later sends response. However, I don't see a response on client.
In nginx logs i see a reponse
In LB logs, that is before docker swarm, we see nothing.
What it can be and how can I debug it properly?

I tried to connect to nginx node from client bypassing load balancer but I get the same result

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.